# C - Rewriting a 2 for loop into a 1 for loop for copying arrays.

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, random

I was given the following problem:

"In function main declare an integer `array` called num1 with 30 elements and declare a second integer `array` called num2 with 21 elements.
To each element of num1 assign a random number between 1 and 50; print the numbers.

In a `for loop`, copy the first 21 numbers from num1 to num2.

In another `for loop` print the element values from num2, seven values per line.  Find an algorithm that will print them from **one loop, not 3 loops**. "

I have been able to narrow down to 2 for loops, but I am having difficulty trying to get everything into one for loop. I'm just not sure how I can copy the arrays from num1 into num2, if I don't use a second for loop.

Here is the work I've done so far. It prints everything correctly, but it's in 2 for loops and not 1.

```
for (j = 0; j < 30; j++) // getting random numbers for num1
{
    num1[j] = 1 + rand() % (50 + 1 - 1);
    printf("%d ", num1[j]);

}
printf("\nThis is num2:\n"); 
for (j = 0; j < 21; j++) // copying num1 array into num2 array, and only taking the first 21 numbers
{
    num2[j] = num1[j];
    printf("%d ", num2[j]);
    if (x % 7 == 0) // this will print num2 with 3 rows each with 7 values 
    {
        printf("\n");

    }
    x++;
}
```

Comment: Try to think of a way that you can combine the loops.   HINT: is there a way you can move the code in loop 2 into loop 1?  You may need to add an if statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you have already done more than the original question asked.

> In function main declare an integer array called `num1` with 30 elements
>   and declare a second integer array called `num2` with 21 elements. To
>   each element of `num1` assign a random number between 1 and 50; print
>   the numbers.

You've done this. Note that there is no restriction on how you can initialize and print the numbers. You can use a `for` or `while` loop or just do the same thing 30 times.

> In a `for` loop, copy the first 21 numbers from `num1` to `num2`.

Done. See my note below, though.

> In another `for` loop print the element values from `num2`, seven values
>   per line. Find an algorithm that will **print** them from one loop, not 3
>   loops. *(emphasis mine)*

Done. You have printed the values in one loop. **Note** that you've gone further than (my reading of) the original question required; you have incorporated the copy and print operations into the same loop. The only thing that concerns me is why the question refers to 3 loops. I would expect a simple implementation of the answer to use two nested loops to print the values. So it's possible that the question was ambiguously worded and that you were right to combine the copy and print operations. I certainly don't think that there's anything more you need to do.

Comment: I can see what you are saying, I could just be reading it wrong and making it seem harder than it actually is. Thank you very much for the advice, and helping me see that I could've just been over thinking it.

Answer (score 0):

If you REALLY want to do everything in a single loop, you could iterate the 30 times plus the 21 for the 2nd section processing and use an if statement for the conditional processing:

```
for (j = 0; j < 30+21; j++) // getting random numbers for num1
{
  if(j < 30)
  {
   num1[j] = 1 + (rand() % 50);
   if(j < 21) 
   {
     num2[j] = num1[j];
   }
   printf("%d ", num1[j]);
  }
  else
  {
    if(j == 30)
      printf("\nThis is num2:");

    if (((j-30) % 7) == 0) 
    {
      printf("\n");
    }
    printf("%d ", num2[j-30]);
  }
}
printf("\n");
```

Comment: why do u say that?

Comment: "To each element of num1 assign a random number between 1 and 50; print the numbers."

Comment: you are right I did miss the print the numbers - it could still be done in a single loop, iterating over 30 + 21 times and assigning num1 numbers when less than 30, and num2 number processing when above.

Comment: modified answer to reflect the initial prints

Answer (score 0):

The formatting won't be the prettiest, but this should be about what you need. The trick is waiting until you've populated it and subtracting from your current index to get the old values.

```
int main(void) {
int num1[30];
int num2[21];

    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        num1[i] = 1 + rand() % (50);
        printf("%d \n", num1[i]);

        if (i<21)
            num2[i] = num1[i];

        if (!(i%7))
            printf("%d %d %d %d %d %d %d\n", num2[i-6], num2[i-5], num2[i-4], num2[i-3], num2[i-2], num2[i-1], num2[i-0]);
        }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: The printout of values in `num1` is mixed up with the values from `num`2